# How to do a Read More over text with some transparency?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am trying to do a Read More button which must be over the hidden text, and the hidden text must have some transparency you can barely see it, like this example:

***(Ignore the turquoise colour cells)***
[image]

I did it at first with SCSS and no JS at all. But now my client change his mine and he wants it that way.
Here is what I have done so far: https://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/zzNKqR

SCSS:

```
// READ MORE BASE
.read-more-wrap {

  .read-more-state
  // .read-more-state: This is the input checkbox. We want this to be the first child after the wrap element.
  // HTML Usage: <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="_uniqueID_" name="toggle" />
    {
      display: none; //We don't want to show the text boxes

      // add ellipsis if it's within a paragraph
      ~ p .read-more-trigger,
      ~ * p .read-more-trigger {
        &:before {
          content: '\2026' ' '; //ellipsis
          color: #444;
        }
      }

      ~ .read-more-trigger, 
      ~ * .read-more-trigger {
      // .read-more-trigger: This is used to trigger the action. It's actually the label for the .read-more-state checkbox, which we declare below.
      // HTML Usage: <label for="_uniqueID_" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
      // SCSS Sytax: When the trigger is a sibling, or the child of any sibling of .read-more-state within .read-more-wrap
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #008dec;
        max-width: 670px;
        margin-bottom: .25em;

        &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
          color: #ff4500;
        }

        &:after {
          content: 'Show more';
          border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
          white-space: nowrap;
          font-size: 90%;
          letter-spacing: -.3px;
        }
      } // end .read-more-trigger

      ~ .read-more-target,
      ~ * .read-more-target {
      // .read-more-target: This is what gets shown or hidden when the trigger is pressed.
      // HTML Usage: <span class="read-more-target">content</span> - Note that this can be a span, a div, a p, or any other element that you want to show or hide, as long as it's a sibling, or the child of a sibling of .read-more-state
      // SCSS Syntax: When the target is a sibling, or the child of any sibling of read-more-state, then that target's state is:
        opacity: 0;
        max-height: 0;
        font-size: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: .125s linear;
      }

      // when .read-more-state is checked:
      &:checked {
        ~ * .read-more-target, 
        ~ .read-more-target {
          opacity: 1;
          max-height: 999em;
          font-size: inherit;
          visibility: visible;
        }

        ~ .read-more-trigger:before,
        ~ * .read-more-trigger:before {
          content: '';
        }

        ~ .read-more-trigger:after,
        ~ * .read-more-trigger:after {
          content: 'Show less';
        }
      }  // &:checked
    } // .read-more-state 
}
// END READ MORE BASE

// BEGIN MOBILE ONLY
.read-more-wrap--mobile {
  @extend .read-more-wrap;
  .read-more-state {
    @media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
      ~ * .read-more-target, 
      ~ .read-more-target {
            opacity: 1;
            max-height: 999em;
            font-size: inherit;
            visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    :checked {
      ~ * .read-more-target, 
      ~ .read-more-target {        
          @media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
            opacity: 1;
            max-height: 999em;
            font-size: inherit;
            visibility: visible;
          }
      }
    }

    ~ .read-more-trigger, 
    ~ * .read-more-trigger {
      @media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
// END MOBILE ONLY

/* Other style */ 
body {
  padding: 2%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="read-more-wrap--mobile">
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="mobile" name="toggle" />
  <h2>Read more wrap</h2>
  <p>Pinterest taxidermy et heirloom, ennui enim eu bicycle rights fugiat nesciunt commodo. High Life food truck jean shorts in. Blog asymmetrical<span class="read-more-target">  cold-pressed photo booth. Neutra chia in, mustache Etsy nostrud plaid kogi. Magna polaroid stumptown aliqua put a bird on it gentrify, street art craft beer bicycle rights skateboard. DIY plaid gentrify, sustainable sapiente seitan mumblecore viral cardigan. Nisi pariatur laborum cornhole kitsch tempor fingerstache Bushwick. </span><label for="mobile" class="read-more-trigger"></label></p>
</div>
```

I tagged JS in case there is a solution with it.
So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have have the `p` have `overflow: hidden` then change the height to match the `scrollHeight` to show full text. You're better at css so I think you can make it look better than mine :)

You should also replace the ids if you plan to have more than 1 at a time, but the expand already takes into factor relativity, so that shouldn't need to change too much.

```js
function expand(target)
{
  let prev = target.previousElementSibling;
  
  prev.style.height = prev.scrollHeight + "px";
  target.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#p {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#read-more {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <p id='p'>Pinterest taxidermy et heirloom, ennui enim eu bicycle rights fugiat nesciunt commodo. High Life food truck jean shorts in. Blog asymmetrical cold-pressed photo booth. Neutra chia in, mustache Etsy nostrud plaid kogi. Magna polaroid stumptown aliqua put a bird on it gentrify, street art craft beer bicycle rights skateboard. DIY plaid gentrify, sustainable sapiente seitan mumblecore viral cardigan. Nisi pariatur laborum cornhole kitsch tempor fingerstache Bushwick. </p>
  <div id='read-more' onclick="expand(this)">
    READ MORE
  </div>
</div>
```